# How to access documents under a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database that has stock data stored on it. Each stock data is stored as a separate collection that the collection name is the stock name, and there are `id, time, open, high, low, close, volume` data stored in each collection for some days for each stock.You can see the structure of each collection in picture below:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to find each collection, and store it's data as a new python dictionary separately. But my code doesn't work properly no errors.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint


myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/") #, username='mongo-admin', password='password')
mydb = myclient["db-data-stock"]
pprint(mydb)
posts = mydb.list_collection_names()


for item in posts:
    for data in item:
        pprint(data)
```

And it only prints the name of the collections not the data inside of them!

The output of the `posts` is a list with contents like:

```
['کیمیا',
 'ونفت',
 'اخزا807',
 'دیران',
 'وزمین',
 'کحافظ',
 'لبوتان']
```

And the output of nested `for`s is like:

```
'ر'
'ک'
'ب'
'ا'
'ف'
'ق'
'ث'
'ج'
'و'
'ا'
'ن'
'ک'
'ی'
'ش'
```

Comment: What `pprint(data)` is printing?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani: It print's out letters of the collection names that `posts` prints.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani: Something like `'ر'
'ک'
'ب'
'ا'
'ف'
'ق'
'ث'
'ج'
'و'
'ا'
'ن'
'ک'
'ی'
'ش'
'1'
'4'
'0'
'2'
'د'
'ت'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over collection name (which is a string) instead of its MongoDB-cursor

I think the below code is what you are looking for:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint


myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/") #, username='mongo-admin', password='password')
mydb = myclient["db-data-stock"]
pprint(mydb)
posts = mydb.list_collection_names()


for item in posts:
    for data in mydb[item].find({}):
        pprint(data)
```

Comment: Why `mydb[item].find({})` doesn't work? And prints something like: `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x244dc042508>`.

Comment: `mydb[item].find({})` is a cursor. If you try to print it, you will get this: `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x244dc042508>`. Instead, you have to iterate it like this: `for doc in mydb[item].find({}):     print(doc)`